# Laravel with Blade Components throws Target Class View does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laradock with Laravel 7.24, and I can't make a Blade template component work.

I've followed the tutorial from the official documentation page, so, inside the docker-machine executed:

```
php artisan make:component Alert
```

And placed the component inside of the layout blade template:

```
<x-alert/>
```

But it throws the following error:

> Target class [Illuminate\Support\Facades\App\View\Components\Alert]
> does not exist. (View: /var/www/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php)

Does anyone know what is the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Might be related. If you're trying to make a component anonymous...
 1. Remove the relevant file in `app/view/components`
 2. Run `php artisan view:clear` to reset compiled views

Answer (score 9):

Experienced with the same problem.
First of all, remove the file from `app/view/components` this path and run
`php artisan view:clear` this command.

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 3):

To use the component anonymous you need to delete class app/View/Components/Alert.php, deleting the view folder worked for me.